# UIImagePickerController With Camera Option in landscape mode in iphone SDK

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape-portrait

I'm going to use UIImagePickerController with source as a camera. by default when i'm capturing the image m able to take the picture in portrait mode. here the problem is that i'm not able to display the same view in landscape mode.

Is there any other way to open the camera in Landscape mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no way to open camera in Landscape mode So we have to customize views as per our need.
You have to add rotation transformation to picture which will match to landscape view. You can hard code it as ,

> Blockquote

CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 117.81)"

> Blockquote